# Does a WSP file export contain webparts and pages?

Tags: solution-package

I have exported a wsp file from sharepoint 2010. I have then imported it into visual studio 2010.

I cant find the pages and web parts that the site had.  Where would they appear?  There is so much in the imported solution and it is very confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you mean you would like to visualy see the webparts and pages?

im afraid that is not possible! unless its a visual webpart (asin you have the ascx that you can view)! webpart is code and only code, what you see in the code within vs2010 gets converted into what you visually see in sharepoint!

what files can you see in your wsp? im confused asto how you can see whats in the wsp? i know you can rename the .wsp to .cab and see whats inside(files), its usually the .dll and .osd files.

development files like .cs .sln and .dll are the files that you need to see code for the webpart. When you build the project it produces a .dll file. It is that file that gets converted among others like manifest ect that produce a .wsp file.

WSP is only a container for those files.

appart from that opening wsp files will only show rubbish that you cant read!

hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Your WSP contains the assets & artifacts that are used to build the site as well as some potential code that might be executed during activation of some features. You won't find the pages because it's part of the site content and not the solution (unless it contains a site template with some predefined pages...), nor you'll find pages with webpart unless they were provisioned by the solution.

Any reason why you'll reverse engineering a WSP instead of working from the actual Visual Studio Solution ? You can easily replace the .wsp by .wsp.cab and see the inner content in a flattened way (manifest.xml is the key file to see if something that you are looking for is present or not).